# Spring Boot Integration with PyTorch Model: Embedding a Pre-trained Network

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, pytorch

I'm working on integrating a pre-trained `PyTorch` model into a `Spring Boot` application. My aim is to leverage the model's inference capabilities within the `REST API` exposed by the application. I've searched online but haven't found a clear guide on the best approach. Could someone please provide some guidance or point me toward helpful resources?

Specific Questions:

- **Preferred Approach:** What's the recommended way to embed a PyTorch
  model in a Spring Boot application? Are there established libraries
  or frameworks that streamline the process?
- **Serialization/Deserialization:** How can I efficiently serialize the
  PyTorch model for deployment within the Spring Boot application? Are
  there specific formats or tools preferred for this task?
- **Model Serving:** Once the model is integrated, how can I create an API
  endpoint within Spring Boot that accepts input data, feeds it to the
  model for inference, and returns the predictions?